# How do you move a face without creating another faces?

Tags: scale

[image]

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHZ7U1bHbFM&feature=youtu.be)

In shown image and video

Number 1 is the problem I don't understand.

Number 2 is the final result I wanted.(mirror modifier in it.)

Number 3 is to test and compare with Number 1

Whenever I try to scale the Number 1 up to Z, it also creates unwanted side faces around it(this happens a lot and always confuses me). But Number 3 scales up properly without creating ones.(Newest objects tend to not create those)

What is the difference between Number 1 and 3? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple vertices on top op each other. Go into edit mode, select all (press a), and then open the tools panel on the left by pressing t. There's an option called "Remove doubles". Press that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you right but I answer it how I understand it.

1. > How do you move a face without creating another faces?

   You are not creating another face. You already have two faces (to be exactly you have more but this isn't the fact) on the surface of the cylinder.
2. > What is the difference between Number 1 and 3?

   In cylinder 1 there is a loopcut. In 3 there is none.

   [image: Loopcut]
3. > What am I doing wrong?

   You are moving a face through another face. This is why it looks like 
   that another face was created. You have to move both, the bottom vertices and the loppcut vertices.

**To Reach your goal**

Model your Cylinder like you want it. Make two loopcuts delete the faces between the loopcuts and fill the howl.

[image]